# popluate combobox value from mysql in python flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

i am new in codding and flask and i want to know how to retrieve the combo box value based on the previous combo box.

i followed the tutorial and successfully to retrieve the first combo box value from the database.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9W2ul2VRRc&t=761s

now based on that value i want to retrieve the second value.  could you please check my code and advice how i need to put the filter condition

suppose i have to combo box first customer_name and second instance_name.
if i choose customer =tcs then corresponding instance_name must be showin in the next combo box like instance_name = tcs_test_33i

```
class custdetail(db.Model):
    cust_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer = db.Column(db.String(50))
    instance_name = db.Column(db.String(50)) 


def Customer_query():
    return custdetail.query

def Customer_query_env():
    return custdetail.query#.filter(custdetail.customer == customer) 


class CustomerForm(FlaskForm):
    opts = QuerySelectField(query_factory=Customer_query, allow_blank=False, get_label='customer')

class CustomerEnv(FlaskForm):
    opts1 = QuerySelectField(query_factory=Customer_query_env, allow_blank=False, get_label='instance_name')


@app.route('/runpage/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = CustomerForm()
    form1 = CustomerEnv()

    form.opts.query = custdetail.query.filter(custdetail.cust_id > 0)
    #form1.opts1.query = custdetail.query.filter(custdetail.customer == format(form.opts.data))


    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return '<html><h1>{}</h1></html>'.format(form.opts.data)

    if form1.validate_on_submit():
        return '<html><h1>{}</h1></html>'.format(form1.opts1.data)

    return render_template('runpage.html', form=form, form1=form1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the sol:

runpage.html file :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" 
         src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var dropdown = {
            customer: $('#select_customer'),
            product: $('#select_product')
        };

        // function to call XHR and update product dropdown
        function updateproduct() {
            var customer = dropdown.customer.val();
            dropdown.product.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            console.log(customer);

            if (customer.length) {
                dropdown.product.empty();
                $.getJSON("{{ url_for('productChange') }}", {customer: customer}, function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    data.forEach(function(item) {
                        dropdown.product.append(
                            $('<option>', {
                                value: item.vals,
                                text: item.vals
                            })
                        );
                    });
                    dropdown.product.removeAttr('disabled');
                });
            }
        }

        // event listener to customer dropdown change
        dropdown.customer.on('change', function() {
            updateproduct();
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/runpage/" method="POST" >
        {{ form.customer}}
        {{ form.product }}
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

--dbconnect.py

```
import MySQLdb
def connection():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost.localhost",
                           user = "usrname",
                           passwd = "pwd123",
                           db = "pythonp")
    c = conn.cursor()
    return c, conn
```

app.py file:

```
from flask import *
import os
from dbconnect import connection
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, request, url_for, redirect, session,Response
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, TextField, PasswordField, validators,SelectField
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from MySQLdb import escape_string as thwart
#from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm 
from wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField
from urllib.request import *
from flask import json
import gc 

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'my unobvious secret key'



class runpageForm(Form):
    customer = SelectField('Select your customer Name', choices=[], id='select_customer')
    product = SelectField('Select your product Name', choices=[], id='select_product')

@app.route('/runpage/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def runpage():

    try:
      form = runpageForm()
      if request.method == "POST" :
            # loading values in SelectFields on page load

            for row in fetch_customer('custdetail', 'customer'):
                  customer = str(row[0])
                  form.customer.choices += [(customer, customer )]   ;
                  #value_customerqq = dict(form.customer.choices).get(form.customer.data)

      return render_template("runpage.html", form=form)
    except Exception as e:
        error = "Invalid credentialsw, try again."
        return(str(e))


@app.route('/productChange/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def productChange():
    try:
      form = runpageForm()
      if request.method == "GET":
               customer = request.args.get('customer')
               print(customer)
               c, conn = connection()
               c.execute("SELECT product FROM custdetail WHERE customer = %s", [customer])
               product = c.fetchall()
               print(product)

               data = [{"vals": x[0]} for x in product]
               print ("hello tript")
               print (data)
               c.close()

      return jsonify(data)

    except Exception as e:
        error = "Invalid customer name, try again."
        return(str(e))
```

Comment: So you took my advice, and learnt how to do method 2 probably from my links, and then accepted your own answer and didn't even both to upvote my answer. In your opinion was that appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

In its basic form Flask is a static renderer of webpages, meaning when the user loads a route, say '/my_page' the python function will be executed, it will generate some variables that are then passed to the webpage and can be rendered, by the jinja2 templating language. At that point the page is created.

If your user then changes something on the page and you need something to be updated then that is called frontend dynamics or reactivity. In this case when your user changes a form element it means that the other form elements must be updated.

There are generally two ways you can integrate this with flask, but both need user side front end Javascript, you can't really avoid this.

**Method 1: Pre compute all possible combinatorics and pass all values to the render template and store them in the javascript and dynamically update just the ones you need when the form changes.**

**Method 2: Build an API function in flask that your javascript can access when the form value changes and it will fetch the values from python (which fetches via SQL) and then the javascript can update the form in the user browser.**

Method 1 is simpler, use it for small combinations when the python processing of all combinations is fast, but this method can add considerably overhead to page loading when there is a lot of processing needed (most of which will be redundant). Method 2 is more efficient and should be used when the processing needed is more complicated or the combinations is large (i.e. you have a lot of users and can't prepopulate all in the render)

A very nice reactive Javascript library that make the above accessible is Vue.js.

**If the above is too complicated for what you are trying to achieve, one solution is to break the 4 combo boxes up. Have a 'next' button after each combo box that is a hyperlink to another flask route, So you essentially have 4 pages, each one an extension of the other. This will allow python to do most of the coding but your front end will be constantly refreshing with new pages when flask re-renders.**

Comment: Yes, i want to complete using Method 2.  could you please provide me with the code for example.

Comment: No, this is not suiting with my example, what in short i want, just want to know how to link combo box with flask using mysql. like combobox shows all value for selection from database

Comment: I know what you want but its a highly specific example and as I said somewhat complex. I don't have the time to code the thing for you and SE is not a coding service. Perhaps someone else will do this for you. The link I gave is actually the method of doing this but you need to be able to devise a means of altering it to suit your specific needs. You can also see here, in the Flask docs.. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/